# What's the best way to "turn off" a javascript function triggered by an event on the page

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have a nav element that onmouseover I'd like to disable the onmouseover of nearby images.

I was thinking that I'd just loop through and collect the images and set their onmouseover to '' and then onmouseout of the nav element set the images onmouseover back to what it was.

Is there a better way to just get the images onmouseover function to turn off/on through onmouseover/onmouseout of the nav elements?

Comment: I'm terribly curious to learn what warrants this need.  Are you dealing with two pointer devices or something?

Comment: If someone mouses over your nav element they cannot also be moused over your images, so why do you need to disable the images?

Comment: The nav extends on top the images which have a mouseover function which is causing issues in IE. But now I am thinking that it might not solve the problem anyway.

If the image mouseover is never triggered, it is fine. But once it is triggered it causes problems with the nav even if I hide the element.

Answer (score 3):

Why not do the following:

1. Point all `onmouseover` events on all images to a single function
2. Point all `onmouseout` events on all images to a single function
3. Have a variable in the global scope, let's say `var imageInFocus = null;`
4. Whenever you enter the function:
   `if(imageInfocus == null)`, assign the current image name to it, and handle that image.
   else, if it's not null, ignore.
    That way, you'll handle just one image at a time.
5. on `onmouseout`, just assign null back to `imageInFocus`, so it will be available for the next image.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. Something like this should do:

```
$("#id_of_your_element").hover(function(){
    $(".other_elements_class").unbind("mouseover").unbind("mouseover");
}, function(){
    $(".other_elements_class").hover(your_mouseover_function, your_mouseout_function);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think all of those things would work, but that turned out not to be my issue. The issue was that something being set in the images mouseover function was still affecting the navigation once the images were rolled over, even if they were  no longer active, being displayed, or had no mouseover events.

Thanks though.